# Generate a PPT File Using iOS Swift - AEXML Library Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, powerpoint

I am trying to generate a PPT file using iOS Swift and the AEXML library, but I am facing some issues with the library. I have followed the documentation and the examples provided, but I am not able to generate a PPT file successfully. Can someone help me with this issue?

I am using the AEXML library to generate a PPT file in my iOS Swift application. I have added the library to my project and followed the instructions provided in the documentation, but I am not able to generate a PPT file successfully.

Here is the code that I am using to generate the PPT file:

```
let pptFile = Presentation()
let titleSlide = pptFile.addSlide()
let title = titleSlide.addTitle()
title.text = "My Presentation"
```

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I have tried to debug the issue, but I am not able to find the root cause of the problem. Can someone help me with this issue?

Here are the steps that I have followed:

1. Added the AEXML library to my project using Cocoapods.
2. Imported the library in my ViewController class.
3. Created an instance of the Presentation class.
4. Added a slide to the presentation using the addSlide() method.
5. Added a title to the slide using the addTitle() method.

I have also tried to generate a PPT file using the OpenXML library, and it is working fine. But I want to use the AEXML library as it provides some additional features that I need.

Can someone please help me with this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no callstack or specific error message when it crashes? Which line make the crash exactly?

Comment: pptFile.addSlide()

Comment: What is `Presentation`? What's `addSlide()`? Are these custom classes?